# Inequality involving independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

We have independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. Why does the following equality hold?
$$P(X>Y)=\int P(X>Y\mid Y=z)f_Y(z) \, dz,$$
where $f_Y$ is the density of $Y$. Any ideas?

Comment: Should it be $f_Y(z)$ rather than $f_X(z)$?

Comment: It is just a simple averaging according to definition i.e. when you don't know the exact value of something you have to average it over its support set....

Comment: This is a special case of the tower property: $$P(X<Y) = E[ P(X<Y\;|\;Y)].$$It does not require independence of $X$ and $Y$. However, you could use independence to further reduce the RHS to $$\int P(X>z)f_Y(z)dz.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It holds because of the law of total probability. I think here it tells us that, it computes the probability of $X$ when bigger than $Y$ for all values of $Y$. But since, both events are independent,

\begin{equation}
 P(A \cap B) = \frac{P(A\mid B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A) \cdot P(B)}{P(B)} = P(A) 
\end{equation}

it can be reduced as,

\begin{equation}
 f(X > Y) = \int P(X > Y = z) f_{Y} (Y = z) \, dz 
\end{equation}

Assuming that $P(X)$ is a discrete function and $f_Y(y)$ a continuous one, the law of total probability can be expressed as,

\begin{equation}
 P(X=x) = \int P (X=x\mid Y=y) f_Y(Y=y) \, dy 
\end{equation}

Comment: The notations $f_y$, $P_x$ and $P_{x\mid y}$ are all absurd, for different reasons, and should be replaced by $f_Y$, $P$ and $P$, respectively.